# Why are Promise's/callbacks still blocking one of my routes in a express server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route '/getdata'. The first user to hit this route will get some data from the database which takes 15 seconds. The second user who hits the route just get send some plain text. Here is the code.

```
let REQUEST_NUMBER = 0;

let asyncDatabaseFetch = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Artifically creating 15 seconds database operation!
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('First request!');
        }, 15000);
    })
} 

app.get('/getdata', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Got request on: \'/getdata\'')
    REQUEST_NUMBER++;
    if(REQUEST_NUMBER == 1) {
        asyncDatabaseFetch().then((val) => {
            res.send(val);
        })
    } else {
        res.send("No data for you!");
    }
});
```

What I expected was that the first user will have to wait 15 seconds for the response, but the next coming users will instantly get the "No data for you!" message.

But, what happens is, the first user has to wait for 15 seconds for his response, and if the second user requested the route just after the first user, he will have to wait out till the request for first user is handled.

I have a couple of questions regarding this behaviour:

1) I'm using Promises, which I thought were non-blocking. So why does the second user still have to wait until the request for first user is done?

2) How do I solve this issue? What if instead of some database query, I want to do some heavy computational work that requires some time. Is there a way to not make other requests wait while this heavy request is served?

Comment: I can't replicate this; the 2nd tab requesting `/getdata` immediately after the first instantly gets the `No data for you!` result.

Comment: can't replicate either

Comment: Your first question does not seem to reproduce.  Your second question is not how one would generally like to design a server (making all users wait for one slow request).  If you really want to do that, then you have to code some synchronization between the requests on the server.  Depending upon exactly what the real objective is there are lots of ways to do that, but basically an incoming request checks some shared state and if it needs to wait, then it registers for a notification when the thing to wait for will be done and then returns, picking up work when the notification arrives.

Comment: Ok so apparently this is something related to browser? Cause I've been trying this for an hour now and everytime I tried, the second 'tab' had to wait for the first 'tab' to get the response. After see how many of you couldn't replicate, i tried to send one request from my Laptop browser and one form my phone and it worked instantly.

Im using Ubuntu with Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100

Comment: I can in fact replicate this if I use two Chrome tabs. Version 76. It's possible that Chrome detects the fact that the same URL is requested twice and waits for the first to load, which makes this a Chrome issue that won't affect your users.